# How to inline an href?

Tags: html, css, href

I have something that looks like:

```
<ContentBlock
    className={'text-gray-300 mt-4'}
>
    Blah blah blah, blah BLAH, blah
    <a href="foo.bar" 
       className={'underline text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300'}>
          foo bar
    </a>
</ContentBlock>
```

When displayed, the href link is always on a newline by itself. How can I make it stay "attached" to the previous text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. first option:

   you can use `display: inline-block` for both, `a` tag, and the element before

   ```css
       .inline-block {
         display: inline-block;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <p class="inline-block"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, !</p>
       <a href="" class="inline-block"> learn more</a>
   ```
2. second option:

   add the anchor tag inside text tag before it

   ```html
       <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, !
         <a href=""> learn more</a>
       </p>
   ```
3. third option:

   wrap them in flex

   ```css
       .flex {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="flex">
         <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, !</p>
         <a href=""> learn more</a>
       </div>
   ```

Comment: Great answer! I think it would be helpful to anyone coming in later to understand that each of these has different implications when the line is broken. The first option will drop the link to the next line when the text wraps, the third option will wrap the text and keep the link off to the side so you have 2 separate groups, only the second approach actually keeps the text as a single unit when there is a wrap.

Answer (score 3):

Something you may consider trying is the adding the CSS "display" property to your  element: `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

You use Tailwind? Then call the class **inline**. It is the same like: `display: inline-block;`

```
<ContentBlock
    className={'text-gray-300 mt-4'}
>
    Blah blah blah, blah BLAH, blah
    <a href="foo.bar" 
       className={'inline underline text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300'}>
          foo bar
    </a>
</ContentBlock>
```